# Replacing numbers in numpy array with the ones in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array, and I'm looking to replace its contents with the numbers of a list by index.

Here's a code snippet to describe it more clearly:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([
              [2, 'something'],
              [2, 'more'],
              [6, 'and more'],
              [11, 'and so on'],
              [11, 'etc..']
             ])

y = [1, 2, 3]
```

I tried to do it by the following code, got an error and couldn't figure why is it occurring.

```
k = x[:, 0]
z = [2, 6, 11]
j = 0
for i in range(z[0], z[-1] + 1):
    k = np.where(i in k, y[j])
    j+=1
```

Error while running the above code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-c48814c42718>", line 4, in <module>
    k = np.where(i in k, y[j])

ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given
```

Output array I want to have:

```
# The output array which I intend to get
output = [
          [1, 'something'],
          [1, 'more'],
          [2, 'and more'],
          [3, 'and so on'],
          [3, 'etc..']
         ]
```

Comment: Your example is not at all clear in how the output array is derived from the import array. Please explain the idea in words, since your example is unclear. Do you want to replace the smallest number in the array's 1st column with the smallest number in the list, the second-smallest with the second-smallest, etc.? If so, is it guaranteed that the first column in the array and the list are sorted in non-decreasing order?

Comment: The output array is what I intend to have from `x`

Comment: Show the full `error`.   Also pay attention to the dtype of the arrays.  I'm guessing they are string dtype.

Comment: edited the question

Comment: What if another `2` appeared later, should it share the same value as the first time `2` appeared, or something different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is one way you can do that:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([
              [2, 'something'],
              [2, 'more'],
              [6, 'and more'],
              [11, 'and so on'],
              [11, 'etc..']
             ])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3])
# Find places where value changes, do cumsum and add a 0 at the beginning, then index y
x[:, 0] = y[np.r_[0, np.cumsum(np.diff(x[:, 0].astype(np.int32)) != 0)]]
# [['1' 'something']
#  ['1' 'more']
#  ['2' 'and more']
#  ['3' 'and so on']
#  ['3' 'etc..']]
```

Note here the result is strings because that is the type of the input array (NumPy will coerce to string unless `dtype=object` is specified). In any case, if you want to have mixed-type arrays, you should consider using a [structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html).

Comment: Thanks @jdehesa, the one-line code worked like a charm!! Moreover, removing `!=0` from the code still works, if I'm not missing out something.

Answer (score 3):

#### `numpy.unique` + `return_inverse=True`

You can create a mapping from differing elements in your column, and use basic numpy indexing to map those values to your input list.

---

```
y = np.array([1, 2, 3])

_, inv = np.unique(x[:, 0], return_inverse=True)

x[:, 0] = y[inv]
```

```
array([['1', 'something'],
       ['1', 'more'],
       ['2', 'and more'],
       ['3', 'and so on'],
       ['3', 'etc..']], dtype='<U11')
```

---

The one caveat to this answer is that if another `2` appears later in the array, it will replace it with `1`, not with a new value, but you will need to clarify your question if that is an issue.

Based on the size of your replacement list, this seems to be the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by getting unique values, ordering them in a brute force manner, and using a for loop to map. You would need to make sure your mapping list (y) is also ordered least to greatest.

```
ind = list(x[i][0] for i in range(len(x)))

lookup = set()
ind = [x for x in ind if x not in lookup and lookup.add(x) is None]

for i in range(len(x)):
           c = ind.index(x[i][0])
           x[i][0] = y[c]

print(x)
```

Output:

```
array([['1', 'something'],
       ['1', 'more'],
       ['2', 'and more'],
       ['3', 'and so on'],
       ['3', 'etc..']], dtype='<U11')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue using a for loop like you currently have and make use of the `y` list you could do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[2, 'something'], [2, 'more'], [6, 'and more'],
              [11, 'and so on'], [11, 'etc..']])
y = [1, 2, 3]

y_index = 0
for i in range(0, x.shape[0] - 1):
  if x[i+1][0] != x[i][0]:
    x[i][0] = y[y_index]
    y_index += 1
  else:
    x[i][0] = y[y_index]
x[-1][0] = y[y_index] # Set last index

print(x)
```

**Output:**

```
[['1' 'something']
 ['1' 'more']
 ['2' 'and more']
 ['3' 'and so on']
 ['3' 'etc..']]
```